# Incorrect height of view after nav controller push

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view that displays horizontal cells that fill the screen (it't an iOS app). Some of the cells have textfields, If the user taps the "next" button the collection view proceeds to the next screen. The keyboard resizes the view that contains the collection view. All this is in a navigation controller. The problem is that when the keyboard is on screen and the user taps next the animation from the navigation controller (push) and the keyboard dismiss overlap. This makes the next view be displayed on the top part of the screen (like the keyboard is still there).

This is the code that resizes the view:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    NSValue *keyboardFrameValue = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    CGRect keyboardFrame = [keyboardFrameValue CGRectValue];
    BOOL isPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation);
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = isPortrait ? keyboardFrame.size.height : keyboardFrame.size.width;

    self.bottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];



    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:(animationCurve << 16) animations:^{
        NSLog(@"keyboard will show");
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:NULL];

}



-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [info[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

    self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:(animationCurve << 16) animations:^{
        NSLog(@"keyb will hide");


        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [self layoutIfNeeded];
        }
    }];

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This more of a workaround than a solution, but could you disable the "next" key when the keyboard is being displayed?

Answer (score 2):

This can be a possible solution of your problem :

on click of next button :

```
        [collectionviewCell.textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I use [self.collectionView endEditing:YES];

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen to the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification instead of UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillHideNotification.
You can handle the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification in the following way:

```
- (void)handleKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardEndFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame fromView:nil];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] integerValue];
    CGFloat keyboardHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height - keyboardEndFrame.origin.y;

    // Constraint animation.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

If this does not help, you can try to avoid animations overlapping using GCD.
Here's a pseudocode:

1) when the user taps the next button, force the current first responder to resign it (you can use [self.view endEditing:YES])

2) dispatch the transition to the next screen asynchronously on the main thread using dispatch_async

EDIT:

Are you testing on a device or in the simulator? Simulator has a few bugs related to the keyboard showing / hiding.

Comment: This is both on device and the simulator

Comment: Exactly the same happens if I use your method in stead of the 2 for keyboard will show/hide

Comment: I experieneced a similar problem few weeks ago. I made some debugging and I found that sometimes the keyboard notification is sent despite the fact that keyboard didn't change its frame. Weird, but the code above made the trick for me.
If you think that the main cause are overlapping animations, try to postpone UINavigationController push animation to the next run loop using GCD.
It can be very complex problem though and I'm not able to help you more without knowing more from your code and UI.